# Using Doorkeeper inside Rails Engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

I am trying to implement doorkeeper into my Rails App. My App consists of 2 mountable engines. Api and CoreApi.

```
  constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
    mount Api::Engine => '/'
  end

  constraints :subdomain => 'core.api' do
    mount CoreApi::Engine => '/'
  end
```

I want to use Doorkeeper in the CoreApi Engine to protect those endpoints with OAuth. I have included the Doorkeeper gem in my gemspec for that engine. I have also set the symbol in the initializer.

```
CoreApi::Doorkeeper = ::Doorkeeper
```

Everything is working except when I try to visit the applications index path for doorkeeper. I ran `rake routes` and the paths for the CoreApi engine list all the doorkeeper paths. The issue is

```
undefined local variable or method `new_oauth_application_path'
```

its referring to the url helper on line 11 of doorkeeper-1.0.0/app/views/doorkeeper/applications/index.html.erb

I can't figure out why this is not resolving. I assume its because doorkeeper is a rails mountable engine and I am trying to mount it inside a rails mountable engine.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more where you put `CoreApi::Doorkeeper = ::Doorkeeper` please? 

Answer (score 0):

Add to first line of `config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb`:

```
Doorkeeper::ApplicationController.send(:include, CoreApi::Engine.routes.url_helpers)
```